# How to set child div border to parent div height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

As you may see in this JSfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/m4qLqppd/, the border height of each "part" is different and does not cover the entire row. It is set to whatever height that particular is and not the height of the parent.

Is there anyway I can get it to always be the height of the parent row "info" without setting a fixed height? I do not want a fixed height because the height of the parent will vary.

I tried setting the height of each part to

```
height: 100%
```

but this does not do it.

Comment: Why you don't use bootstrap table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/m4qLqppd/2/)

For the `%` height to work, you will have to set the height of all the parent elements also in `%`, ie you have to specify the height for both `html` and `body` in `%` too. Thus in your code, you will have to add `height:100%` to `html,body` in your CSS.

The updated CSS would be as follows

```
html,body{
    height:100%;
}
```

**UPDATE**

See the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/m4qLqppd/4/) with all the children occupy full height of the parent. In the updated fiddle, I've added a class named `full-width`, which has a height `100%`, to all the parent elements.

Comment: In the fiddle you provided, the borders next to "number" and "name" still do not cover the entire area

Comment: that is because you dont have the height of rows and col-md-* in %. Give it a class and assign 100% height. It will solve the problem..pls do ask me if you need any help.

Comment: Thanks, but the second address is hidden now. Is there a way to make the parent div's height get taller or shorter depending on how much data there is in the part? Hope this makes sense. I tried changing the percentage of height inside "info" but that is not what I am looking for as it is pretty much the same as fixing the height

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap columns take up only necessary height , they wont stretch 100% . There is another option : Remove bootstrap classes and use flexbox properties css . It more native for responsive design :

try this structure :

html :

```
<div class=" info">   

   <div class="part">      
        <h6>Address</h6>      
        <p>100001 East village road, London UK</p> 
    <p>100202 West village road, London UK</p> 
    </div>  

   <div class="part">     
         <h3>1</h3>    
     </div>    



            <div class="part ">          
                <h6>Number</h6>         
                <p>1</p>        
        </div>

            <div class="part ">          
                <h6>Name</h6>          
                <p>John Marie Ann Frank Jacob</p>       
            </div>      

    </div>    


</div>
```

css :

```
.info {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;

    display: flex;

}

.info .part {
    position:relative;
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 10px;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-basis: auto;
}
```

Proof : https://jsfiddle.net/w5dq0r3k/

Hope this helps

Comment: This is a really cool solution but it seems like if there are a lot of elements or if the width is narrow then parts of the words gets hidden? like "number" in https://jsfiddle.net/w5dq0r3k/3/

Comment: Correct , and at a certain media query you can add flex-wrap: wrap; to the parent container and that would take care of your issue , check here : https://jsfiddle.net/w5dq0r3k/6/

Comment: maybe it is possible to get around this by maybe adding a span element or something next to every "part" and add a border to that element?

Comment: of course this element has to be same height as parent

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a good use case for an HTML table. It appears that the content is actually tabular data. By using an HTML table, it's possible to create the visual design you're seeking.

### HTML

```
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Info</th>
            <th>Number</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>100001 East village road, London UK</td>
            <td>lorem ipsum</td>
            <td>one</td>
            <td>John, Marie, Ann, Frank, Jacob</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2301 West village St, London UK</td>
            <td>lorem ipsum</td>
            <td>two</td>
            <td>Harry</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>345 Endon Rendon, London UK</td>
            <td>lorem ipsum</td>
            <td>three</td>
            <td>Bill</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```